# How to call a method when clicking an asp:RadioButton?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, forms, radio-button

I have a form which is activated by pressing on an `ImageButton`, besides that I'm trying to make that form fire when clicking a `RadioButton`, but when I've directed the `OnCheckedChanged` to the image method the input variables didn't match. so I created an alternate method that takes no arguments, but in that case it doesn't fire unless I press the ImageButton, and when I do that it runs the "no argument method" if you pressed any of the radio buttons before pressing the `ImageButton`.

now, how can I make the `RadioButton` act like the `ImageButton` in the sense that it would cause the form to fire when pressed?

thnx for the help

ASP.NET Page:

```
`<form method="post" runat="server">
        <h1 style="font-family:inherit;margin-left:20%">enter input</h1>
       <div >
           
           <input name="searchbar" type="search" style="width:50%;margin-left:20%;padding:5px;border-radius:8px;" />
           <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/magnifying-glass.png" OnClick="SearchPhone"  runat="server" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
           <table style="float:right;">
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        <asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="OrderBy1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" Checked/>
                   </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="OrderBy2" runat="server" on OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged"/>
                    
                  </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="OrderBy3" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged"/>order by year<br />
                   </td>
              </tr>
        </table>
       </div> 
    </form>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AutoPostBack="true"`

```
 <form method="post" runat="server">
        <h1 style="font-family:inherit;margin-left:20%">enter input</h1>
       <div >

           <input name="searchbar" type="search" style="width:50%;margin-left:20%;padding:5px;border-radius:8px;" />
           <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/magnifying-glass.png" OnClick="SearchPhone"  runat="server" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/>
           <table style="float:right;">
               <tr>
                   <td>
                        <asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="OrderBy1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" Checked/>
                   </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="OrderBy2" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>

                  </td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                   <td>
                       <asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="OrderBy3" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>order by year<br />
                   </td>
              </tr>
        </table>
       </div> 
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the **aspnet** page you need to do something like this with "OnClick"

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="order by" ID="yourMethod" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckedChanged" OnClick="yourMethod_Click" Checked/>
```

On the **yourform.aspx.cs** you need to create the method to fire the OnClick

```
protected void yourMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //do here what you want.
}
```

Use the same ID of the method and the RadioButton like I did above on my code.